# Resfreshing div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to split a number into divs. Now if we press submit multiple times it splits the same number multiple times. I want it to start from zero again and split the values rather than mixing it up.

Here is the issue attached

[image].

This is output I want if we click submit multiple times
[image]

```js
let res = [];
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let cdiv = document.querySelector('#clr');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let num = Number(document.querySelector('#num').value);
  let sp = Number(document.querySelector('#split').value);
  console.log(num)
  console.log(sp)
  if (num > 0) {
    if (sp > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < sp; i++) {
        res.push(Math.floor(num / sp));
      }
      let rem = num % sp;
      for (let i = 0; i < rem; i++) {
        res[i]++
      }
      cdiv.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let color = "#9a5f2b"
        let colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
        colorDiv.style.width = `${100 * res[i]}%`;
        colorDiv.style.height = '50px';
        colorDiv.style.margin = '5px';
        let text = document.createTextNode(`${res[i]}`);
        colorDiv.appendChild(text);
        cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
      }


    } else {
      let color = "#9a5f2b";
      let text = document.createTextNode("Error: both inputs should be greater than 0.");
      let colorDiv = document.createElement("div");
      colorDiv.style.padding = '5px';
      colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
      colorDiv.appendChild(text);
      cdiv.innerHTML = "";
      cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
    }
  } else {
    let color = "#9a5f2b";
    let text = document.createTextNode("Error: both inputs should be greater than 0.");
    let colorDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colorDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
    colorDiv.appendChild(text);
    cdiv.innerHTML = "";
    cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor like I did for you. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and read [ask]. Include your debugging details in the form of a [repro] that also contains your necessary HTML and CSS markup. JS alone in most cases is not helpful. Last but not least, meet the formatting guidelines. A question should never start with code or pictures as search engines would only find the first few lines as a summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you forgot to empty the array with the answers. To fix this i just moved the let res = []; into the eventhandler.

```js
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let cdiv = document.querySelector('#clr');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  let res = [];
  event.preventDefault();
  let num = Number(document.querySelector('#num').value);
  let sp = Number(document.querySelector('#split').value);
  console.log(num)
  console.log(sp)
  if (num > 0) {
    if (sp > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < sp; i++) {
        res.push(Math.floor(num / sp));
      }
      let rem = num % sp;
      for (let i = 0; i < rem; i++) {
        res[i]++
      }
      cdiv.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let color = "#9a5f2b"
        let colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
        colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
        colorDiv.style.width = `${100 * res[i]}%`;
        colorDiv.style.height = '50px';
        colorDiv.style.margin = '5px';
        let text = document.createTextNode(`${res[i]}`);
        colorDiv.appendChild(text);
        cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
      }


    } else {
      let color = "#9a5f2b";
      let text = document.createTextNode("Error: both inputs should be greater than 0.");
      let colorDiv = document.createElement("div");
      colorDiv.style.padding = '5px';
      colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
      colorDiv.appendChild(text);
      cdiv.innerHTML = "";
      cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
    }
  } else {
    let color = "#9a5f2b";
    let text = document.createTextNode("Error: both inputs should be greater than 0.");
    let colorDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colorDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
    colorDiv.appendChild(text);
    cdiv.innerHTML = "";
    cdiv.appendChild(colorDiv);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="num" name="num">
    <input type="number" id="split" name="split">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="clr">
  </div>
</div>
```